# MySQL Full Text Search in subquery returning no results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm setting up the API for my typeahead input which returns users by name and have chosen MySQL full text search rather than concatenating the first, middle and last name so the user can have more flexibility when entering names, without worrying about the correct order.

E.g. both 'Carolina Del', 'Delgado Caro', etc will match the user with corresponding values in the user_names table of first_name="Carolina", middle_name="", last_name="Delgado".

For some reason I'm getting zero results when using full text search after the user/user_names constraint, but I do get correct results when using LIKE.

The following gives 0 results

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `users`
    WHERE (select count(*) from `user_names`
        WHERE `user_names`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        AND MATCH(first_name, middle_name, last_name)
        AGAINST ('+carolina' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ) >= 1;
```

When used with LIKE we get 47 results

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `users`
    WHERE (select count(*) FROM `user_names`
        WHERE `user_names`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        AND `first_name` LIKE "%carolina%")
    >= 1;
```

And to show that the full text indices are working correctly, here is a query directly on the user names table that also gives 47 results

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `user_names`
    WHERE MATCH(first_name, middle_name, last_name)
     AGAINST ('+carolina' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

For what it's worth, I'm using this in a Laravel query builder scope, but since the SQL (above) that it produces isn't working, I need to first understand why.

```
public function scopeForContactName($query, $name)
{
return $query->whereHas('contact.name', function ($query) use ($name) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($name) {
            $q->whereRaw("MATCH(first_name, middle_name, last_name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", [$name]);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by setting the index storage as ascending.

I was previously creating the indexes like so:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX full_text_index ON `user_names` (`first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`)
```

The following adjusted SQL fixed the problem:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX full_text_index ON `user_names` (`first_name` ASC, `middle_name` ASC, `last_name` ASC)
```

This seems to go against the documentation for MySQL which states:

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.
>   [MySQL 5.7 Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

But anyway, works for me!

Comment: Since `FULLTEXT` has no concept of `ASC` or `DESC`, I am surprised that this made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The first query does not make sense.  The subquery returns 1 line -- a count; the outer query should see *exactly* one line to count.

What do you get from this formulation?

```
SELECT count(*)
    FROM `users` AS u
    JOIN `user_names` AS un  ON un.`user_id` = u.`id`
    WHERE  MATCH(un.first_name, un.middle_name, un.last_name)
           AGAINST ('+carolina' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

It makes more sense (to me) to put the names in the `users` table, not a separate table.